# GraphQL should call HTTP or API directly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, graphql

I want to use GraphQL in my project, so I want to know which one is the better option:

```
public class UserQuery : ObjectGraphType<object>
{
    public UserQuery(UserData data)
    {
        Name = "Query";

        Field<User>("user", resolve: context => data.GetUser(1));                        
    }
}
```

So for implementing data.GetUser(1), I have a two options:

**Option 1: Call Http endpoint and fetch the response through the HttpResponse**

```
var client = new Restclient("BaseUrl");
client.Execute(new RestRequest("api/v1/account/1"));
```

- **Advantage**: Doen't need to validate the request and response, also all custom filtering and exception handling will be applied automatiaccly*
- **Disadvantage**: Double Http call, also return bigger response*

**Option 2: Call Api directly through the Controller**

```
var controller = new AccountController();
controller.GetById(1);
```

- **Advantage**: Return lighter object and better performance*
- **Disadvantage**: Have to apply all validations and exceptions handling again.*

Comment: I want to help, but I'm not sure what these options are saying - could you post a code sample or something?

Comment: thanks @stubailo, hard to write code for these options, just tried add small code to make them more clear.

Comment: Neither of those snippets use GraphQL though - it seems very REST-specific. That's part of why I am confused.

Comment: @stubailo, Hope the changes help you

Comment: Ohhhh! I see what you are asking now :] thanks! The missing piece for me is that you are trying to implement a GraphQL _Server_, and wondering how to talk to your existing data. I was thinking about the client side part so was very confused.